# how to use information given in a python while loop?

Tags: python

I made a program that looks like:

```
n = eval(input("enter a whole number: "))
x = 1
print (x)
while x != n:
    x = x + 1
    print (x)
```

This code produces a list from 1 to the given whole number n.

What would i do to be able to interact with this list making a second column that gave the square of the adjacent number?

something like

```
1 1 
2 4
3 9
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to show the square of 1, you need to initialize `x` as `0` and delete `print(x)` from your third line

this should do it:

```
n = eval(input("enter a whole number: "))
x = 0
while x != n:
    x = x + 1
    print (x, " ", x**2)
```

This code prints `x` and `x**2` (the value of '`x ^ 2`') separated by a space.

Comment: I do not know what the downvote is for, this outputs exactly what he needs

Comment: @vilty no problem, please accept answer if this helped you

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you are looking for:

```
n = eval(input("enter a whole number: "))
x = 1
print (x)
while x != n:
    x = x + 1
    p = x * x
    print (x, p)
```

I would urge caution on using eval() so lightly though, you can use the int() function to run a string as an integer. Here is how I would write that code:

```
n = int(input("enter a whole number: "))
x = 0
while x != n:
    x = x + 1
    p = x * x
    print (x, p)
```

EDIT: Updated code

Comment: Why would you evaluate `int(n)` every time through the loop, instead of once when setting `n`?

Comment: I am new to python and that did not occur to me, but it does make sense, I will update the code

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use a list of lists.  Using a generator expression,

```
nums = [[n, n**2] for n in range(1,int(input("Enter a number"))]
```

So if you input `10`, `nums[1,1]` will be `2`.

So to print this out,

```
for i in nums:
    print(i[0] + " " + i[1])
```

**This is by far the simplest way to go.**